# Concatenating strings in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

How do I get both values represented by `i` and `j` into the `getSheetByName` function?

Disclaimer: I am brand new at coding and am probably asking the wrong questions. My goal is to create a simple code that will delete sheets automatically by looping through the sheet names: Week 1, Week 2, etc.

Here's my code so far:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var i = "Week "
  var j = 32
  var mysheet = sheet.getSheetByName(i&j)
  sheet.deleteSheet(mysheet)
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote it, instead of commenting on the answer with "Thank you"

Answer (score 13):

In your code you have written `i&j` that's not the syntax to concat in Google apps script. Instead you can simply use `i + j`.
For looping you'll need to use any loop, like for, while, do-while.

Combining these suggestions, here is my final suggestion.

Try something like this [By using 'try' here I mean, simply don't copy-n-paste and use. Try to understand and write your own code, curated for your specific need. Maybe that way, we'll grow/learn more]

```
function myFunction() {
  var START_WEEK = 1; //Put your starting week count here
  var END_WEEK = 2; //Put your ending week count here
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var pre_name = "Week"
  var i;
  for (i = START_WEEK; i <= END_WEEK; i++) {
    try {
      spreadSheet.deleteSheet(spreadSheet.getSheetByName(pre_name + " " + i))
    } catch (exp) {
      //Maybe sheet with that name is not found
      Logger.log(exp.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

This code loop through all sheet whose name start with `"Week "` and then followed by week count, up till the end week count and if that's found it's deleting them.

Make sure you put in `START_WEEK` and `END_WEEK` properly.

Let me know if this doesn't work for you or if you have any query.

Thanks