# Auto-archive monthly by concatenation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, archive

now that I have an "auto-change-date" function in my spreadsheet that automatically updates the "date" field when I make a change in the "comment" field.

It would be very helpful now, to have an "automatic archive" that copies the content from the "comment" field whenever updated and concatenates it with the existing string from the last comment.

This way I want to be able to delete the "comment" field - content and still keep ALL generated comments in this new "archive" field.

I have prepared a playground to give that all a try. Maybe you can just fill it up and add a column for your changes. Please also consider, that there is an auto-date function running in the background concerning my last issue.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lWlPhS-XF0dtOZ4kOS9LU8haxcF5cWBKdbzp_lh1Z9I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenating strings in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672953/concatenating-strings-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var text; 

  if (column==2) { //Replace 2 with the column number of your comments cell//
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(row,column+1); //If the date is in the next column
    var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd.MM.yyyy');
    newRange.setValue(today);
  }
  if (column == 2){
    text = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
    sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(text + e.value+".");
  }
}
```

I updated the code in the sheet you provided, adding the if statement at the bottom of your function, I tested by editing the comments and they got appended to the 4th column.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: Hey there! Could you please help me correct the script code for the 3 sheets in this file? The comment rows shall always trigger the update rows (changedate) and the docu rows (archive). That would really help me a lot.

Comment: oh and how to replace the date in the update row to date + time utc+1 ?

Comment: @NesElm You should open a new question with this issue, just because it's been so long since the answer was posted. That being said, take a look at [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) to be able to work with multiple sheets, you can use that to get the sheets and then loop through them with my code. As for your other requests, you should explain them a bit more in the new question.